# Cordova app scrolling Android

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, mobile

I'm currently working on an Android app that displays a simple html-document with some css. However, the html changes based on the day, once I've gotten that implemented at least, so there will some days where it will have more elements than it did previously. Now, where the problem lies, is that when there are a many elements, the bottom ones won't show. They are hidden outside the screen, and there is no scrolling.

How would I go about making the page scrollable? This is only for android. I can't use iScroll, seeing that it requires a list-structure in the html, which I don't have and it would be a pain to rewrite the script that makes the html file :/

Thanks

Comment: dunno if this works, but I'm bumping this